# I can't breed my dragons! What am I missing?

Tags: dragonvale

In my account on Dragonvale, it won't let me breed my sun dragon with my blue moon dragon.

Does anybody know if I need the epic breeding cave?

I have been waiting for over 156 hours for both of these dragons to hatch and its terrible that I can't breed them.

Comment: Well, when a boy dragon and a girl dragon love each other *very much*...

Answer (score 5):

***Epic*** dragons are only breedable with others that can live in the same habitat.  So [Sun](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_Dragon) (Sun Habitat) is not compatible with [Blue Moon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Moon_Dragon) (Moon Habitat).  But there are some Sun/Moon crossbreeds like [Solar Eclipse](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Eclipse_Dragon), which can breed with both.  The Epic Breeding Island doesn't have anything to do with it.

We have questions already on the site for most of the Epic and Limited dragons, so if there is one you are shooting for try searching the DragonVale tag, or edit your question.

Comment: The "same habitat" part only applies to epic dragons; you can breed a plant and a fire dragon despite neither being able to use the other's habitat.

Comment: Excellent clarification @Shadur .  That what I meant to say :) . Edited.